# Redirect users to their specified email accounts with receiver and message fields pre-filled

Tags: django, email

I have an email address "myaddress@gmail.com". I have created a django form that has a text field and a button. I want to redirect anyone who types a message in the text box to their respective emails so that they can send the message they typed to "my address". This means that as they log in to their email accounts, their message boxes should already be filled with the message they typed and the receiver field should already have "myaddress@gmail.com". The problem is how to redirect the users to their email accounts and prefill the specified fields.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this isn't possible. you want that someone will fill a form within your site and by pressing a button it will spawn their email client and inject the subject/message to to a new message ? What if I use a web-based email client ? The only solution I have for you is to use the mailto:myaddress@email.com so when pressing a button it will let them fill in an email to a specific address using their favorite email client.

Comment: @Nuno_147 gmail works with `mailto:` Others possibly might as well, but I don't use anything other than gmail.

Comment: I know. thats what I said. I suggested him to use mailto. but I didnt know you can set the subject/content

Comment: Let me further clarify my question. The User will log in to either gmail or yahoo but the page displayed  upon login will be the compose email page with the receiver field already set to my address. That is what I want to accomplish. I know a mobile application "whatsapp" on symbian S40 that does this but  hav no idea how they do it or how to implement it on my website.

Answer (score 1):

If the user has set a **default email program**, most of them will be triggered on `mailto:`. I know gmail works with `mailto:` as well, and its possible that other web email services might. All desktop email clients - again ***only if it is set as the default email program*** will work on `mailto:`

The format is:

`mailto:[emailaddress]?header=value&header1=value1....&headerN=valueN`

Here is an example that sets the subject of the email automatically:

`<a href="mailto:me@gmail.com?subject=Hello%20there&body=Email%20Contents!">Email me</a>`

Comment: Let me further clarify my question. The User will log in to either gmail or yahoo but the page displayed upon login will be the compose email page with the receiver field already set to my address. That is what I want to accomplish. I know a mobile application "whatsapp" on symbian S40 that does this but hav no idea how they do it or how to implement it on my website

Comment: Yes, that's what will happen. Why don't you try it out?

Comment: Pls Can u help me with this too?  Am using gmail smtp to send email messages and it works fine. The only problem is that I want receipients of the email to reply to a different email address. In other words I send them an email as from "me@gmail.com" but when they click reply the message should be replied to "another@gmail.com" or "another@yahoo.com". how can i accomplish this please